# Synchronize method based on the request parameter

Tags: java, multithreading, grails

I have been trying to implement a efficient approach for concurrent call to rest api. I have been getting optimistic locking exception frequently.

I have a video chat controller and a start method inside it. when two or more user try to join the same video chat simultaneously it throws the optimistic locking exception as there is a update on the same db record. 
To avoid that i want it to work as when the request is for same video chat then it should synchronize threads otherwise it should not.

So basically i want to create a waiting queue of simultaneous threads for video chat with same id.

I would really helpful if can have a idea of pseudo code for this since i am not sure how can i achieve this as i am very new to multithreading.

Comment: synchronized is not the proper answer. It will fail as soon as you have two servers, for scalability or redundancy purposes. Retry if that's possible, or dispay a useful message to the user, or use pessimistic locks.

Comment: This sounds like a design problem, if you're basically getting an exception every time.  Pessimistic locking might be needed, but I'd look at how the code behind the Rest is implemented.  It feels like you could queue the requests up and add them one at a time without having report any conflicts

Comment: If you want to add retries, look at at Spring retry